# Null point exception on embedded Kafka

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, reactive-kafka

I am using embedded Kafka for unit testing a spring boot application. I am using the code - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/29a3bd2021c49b700d4f3835c7ced642322c2faf/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/reactive/ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L76 as reference.

Here is my code:

```
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = TestServiceTests.REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC, partitions = 2)

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableKafka
@DirtiesContext

public class TestServiceTests {

public static final String REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC = "reactive_int_key_topic";

@Autowired
private static ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate;

@Autowired
private ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, List<String>> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;

@Before
public void setUpBeforeClass() {
    Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils
            .consumerProps("reactive_consumer_group", "false",EmbeddedKafkaCondition.getBroker());
    reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate =
            new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String>(setupReceiverOptionsWithDefaultTopic(consumerProps));
}


private static ReceiverOptions<String, String> setupReceiverOptionsWithDefaultTopic(
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps) {

    ReceiverOptions<String, String> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(consumerProps);
    return basicReceiverOptions
            .consumerProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
            .addAssignListener(p -> assertThat(p.iterator().next().topicPartition().topic())
                    .isEqualTo(REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC))
            .subscription(Collections.singletonList(REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC));
}

@Test
public void consumeServiceReturnsFlux() {

    TestService testService = new TestService(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate, reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate);

    Flux<String> actual = testService.consumeService();

}
```

I get the following exception at the line EmbeddedKafkaCondition.getBroker()

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(KafkaTestUtils.java:82)
        at ServiceTests.setUpBeforeClass(ServiceTests.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(KafkaTestUtils.java:82)
    at com.oracle.gbucs.collect.CollectdCollectorServiceTests.setUpBeforeClass(CollectdCollectorServiceTests.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54251', transport: 'socket'
```

I think I am missing a setting where my embeddedKafka is set not correct and hence is NULL. But I have not been able to figure out the reason. If someone can help me understand what I am missing will be of great help.

Comment: 1.  Please add the complete stacktrace to the question.  2. Please reformat the code so that the lines aren't so long that StackOverflow puts needs to use a horizontal scroll bar.  That makes it (too) difficult to read the code snippets.

Comment: I have added the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I am figuring out how to reformat the code to be in multiple lines, when I tried it messed up the formatting

Comment: Re formatting.  It is simple.  Just manually insert line breaks for lines that are longer than ~80 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that you use this `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

According the `EmbeddedKafkaCondition` you can't use its `getBroker()` in the Spring context environment:

```
if (element.isPresent() && !springTestContext(element.get())) {

            EmbeddedKafka embedded = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(element.get(), EmbeddedKafka.class);
            // When running in a spring test context, the EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer will create the broker.
```

So, your `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` must be configured slightly different way:

```
@Autowired
private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

@Before
public void setUpBeforeClass() {
    Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils
            .consumerProps("reactive_consumer_group", "false", this.embeddedKafkaBroker);
    reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate =
            new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String>(setupReceiverOptionsWithDefaultTopic(consumerProps));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Working sample:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EmbeddedKafka
@EnableKafka
public class WithSpringTestContextTests {

    @Autowired
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUpBefore() {
        assertThat(embeddedKafkaBroker).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated the code as per your suggestion, but I get the same exception. Do you think I am missing any setting I need to do to setup embeddedKafka ?

Comment: Hm. How that work for you if you really use JUnit 5 annotation `@BeforeEach` not that from JUnit 4 `@Before`?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.